# Isn't my example contradicting that $\mathcal C[0,1]$ with sup norm is complete

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

We know that $\mathcal C[0,1]$ with sup norm is complete. However if we take the sequence of functions $(f_n)$ as below then one can see the internal distance between two functions $f_m,f_n$ are tending to zero at a point as $m,n$ are getting larger. However $f_n$ is tending nowhere as the left nonzero part of $f_n$ is tending to a vertical line and hence converge to the discontinuous function which is $0$ at 0 and $1-x$ in $(0,1]$:

[image]

So where am I going wrong?

Comment: "the internal distance between two functions $f_m,f_n$ are tending to zero at a point as $m,n$ are getting larger" Can you provide proof of this claim?

Comment: This picture is a bit misleading. What is supposed to be the value of $f_n\left(\frac1n\right)$?. Is it $1$, or is it something like $\frac{1}n$? In the latter case, the sequence indeed converges uniformly, and the limit function is $0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

The pointwise limit of your function exists: the limit has
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x = 0\\
1 - x & 0 < x \le 1
\end{cases}
$$

Of course, that function is not continuous, so there's still an apparent problem. Ask yourself: if you call your individual functions $f_n$, what's the sup-norm distance from $f_n$ to my $f$? Or, indeed, from $f_n$ to $f_k$ for any $k$ and $n$? (Hint: if $n > k$, the difference $f_n(x) -
 f_x(x)$ is largest at $x = \frac{1}{n+1}$.)

Comment: Thank you ........Mathematics is amazing