# Is it correct way to show that $\mathcal C_{\mathcal C}(\mathbb R)$ is incomplete

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

This question below is inspired by [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2519932/isnt-my-example-contradicting-that-mathcal-c0-1-with-sup-norm-is-complete). Based on the thought acquired from there, I was trying to solve the following question from [Kesavan's Functional Analysis](http://www.hindbook.com/index.php/functional-analysis):

> [image]

**Here is my attempt:**

For $n\in\mathbb N,$ define $f_n:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ by

$f_n(x)=\dfrac{1}{m}\sin x,$ if $(m-1)\pi\le x\le m\pi$ for some $m\in\{1,2,...,n\}$

$=0,$ otherwise

Choose $\epsilon>0.$ Then $\exists~p\in\mathbb N$ such that $\epsilon>\dfrac{1}{p+1}.$

Then for $m,n\ge p,$ $||f_m-f_n||=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|\dfrac{1}{\min\{m,n\}+1}|\le\dfrac{1}{p+1}<\epsilon$.

**So $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy.**

If possible let $f_n\to f$ in $\mathcal C_{\mathcal C}(\mathbb R).$ Then $\text{supp}f\subset[a,b]$ for some $a,b\in R.$

Choose an odd natural number $k\in\mathbb N$ such that $k.\dfrac{\pi}{2}>b$ Then $f(k.\dfrac{\pi}{2})=0.$

But $f_n(k.\dfrac{\pi}{2})=\dfrac{1}{\frac{k-1}{2}+1}=\dfrac{2}{k+1}~\forall~n\ge k$ since $\frac{k-1}{2}\pi\le\frac{k}{2}\pi\le\frac{k+1}{2}\pi.$

So $||f_n-f||\ge|f_n(k.\dfrac{\pi}{2})-f(k.\dfrac{\pi}{2})|=\dfrac{2}{k+1}$ for all $n\ge k,$ a contradiction.

**Hence $\mathcal C_{\mathcal C}(\mathbb R)$ is not complete.**

> Am I correct?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but should the $\max\lbrace m, n \rbrace$ be a minimum instead?

Comment: @TheoBendit YES YES

Comment: @TheoBendit: Is it correct now?

Comment: I also think you want your $k$ to be odd. If $k$ is even then $f\left(k \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 0$.

Comment: @TheoBendit: Ohh that's also true.

Comment: Other than that, I think it's fine.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks so much. I have rectified it.

Comment: Careful, $f\left(k \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \frac{2}{k+1}$, when $k$ is odd.

Comment: OMG let me think

Comment: @TheoBendit: How about now?

Comment: As I see it, $\frac{k - 1}{2}\pi \le k \frac{\pi}{2} < \frac{k + 1}{2} \pi$, so by the definition of $f_n$, we must have $f_n\left(k \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \frac{2}{k+1}$. You need to change the $\frac{1}{k+1}$ and the $\frac{1}{k}$.

Comment: Where to change 1/(k+1)?

Comment: In the 3rd and 4th last lines of your question.

Comment: flawless now???

Comment: Flawless now. :-)

Comment: Finally........You are awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine. In fact, using your idea, I'd like to offer a streamlined version:

Take any function $0<f<1$, with support in $[0,1].$ A triangle will do, or if you want your functions to be differentiable, a bump function.

Now translate $f$ by defining $f_n(x)=f(x-n).$ Then each $f_n$ is supported in $[n,n+1]$ and the supports are disjoint.

Now just define $F_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f_k(x)}{k+1}.$ Then, if $n>m,\ $ $|F_n(x)-F_m(x)|\le \frac{1}{m+1}$ so $(F_n)$ is Cauchy, but the limit function $F$ is clearly not compactly supported.

Comment: Wow such a nice proof